# Можно ли использовать директории при использовании @import в scss?

Tags: scss

`@import "global/*";`  не рабоатет:

> Error: File to import not found or unreadable: global/*
>          Parent style sheet: stdin
>           on line 5 of stdin @import  'global/*';

на что заменить *, чтобы выбрать все файлы содержащиеся в папке?

p.s. если указать `@import "global/layout.scss";` - то все отлично, но не возможно же указывать отдельно все файлы проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Ну и почему же невозможно? Именно так и делают - указывают все нужные файлы по одному. Тем более, в css важен порядок подключения.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [sass-globbing](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing) или [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails).

Там можно:

```
 @import "global/*"
```